# Saving png sequence as WebP in pil makes background opaque black

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

**Problem**: When saving in `Image` sequence as gif with transparency, it works great, but when saving as webp, the transparency is lost in all frames.

**Using**: Python (Latest) with PIL (Latest)

**Question**: How can this be fixed, and what is causing it?

Code:

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageSequence


def gen_frame(im: Image) -> Image:
    alpha = im.getchannel('A')
    # Convert the image into P mode but only use 255 colors in the palette out of 256
    im = im.convert('RGB').convert('P', palette=Image.ADAPTIVE, colors=255)
    # Set all pixel values below 128 to 255 , and the rest to 0
    mask = Image.eval(alpha, lambda a: 255 if a <= 128 else 0)
    # Paste the color of index 255 and use alpha as a mask
    im.paste(255, mask)
    # The transparency index is 255
    im.info['transparency'] = 255
    return im


im = Image.open("input_gif.gif")

im_list = []

for frame in ImageSequence.Iterator(im):
    # perform some functions on the image frames

    frame = frame.convert('RGBA').resize((512, 512), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    frame = gen_frame(frame)

    im_list.append(frame)

img = im_list[0]
imgs = im_list[1:]

img.save("output_gif.gif", save_all=True, append_images=imgs, duration=50, loop=0, optimize=False, disposal=2)
# works correctly, as intended

img.save("output_webp.webp", save_all=True, append_images=imgs, duration=50, loop=0, optimize=False, disposal=2)
# Transparency loss in the webp format
```

### input gif:

[image: 1]

### output gif:

[image: 2]

### output webp:

[image: 3]

Comment: Please ensure your question is **minimal** - that means the fewest lines possible to show the problem. Can you reproduce it with a list of a red, a green and a blue image you create from scratch in a 6-line program? Oftentimes you will find the problem yourself when you remove extraneous material. Thank you.

Comment: Hmm... In regards to your new question about WebP,  the [docs](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html#webp) say "The specifics of Pillow’s capabilities with this format are currently undocumented." So it's hard to say what works and what doesn't, and how to make it function properly.

Comment: Could you supply the input image? When I take your output image and use it as input, it appears (at least in chrome, windows 10) to show a white background, which is consistent with the input image (your output image).

Comment: @ShanerM13 you see a white background in the GIF shown? It's not transparent?

Comment: @ShanerM13 yes the transparent image background shows as light-gray in chromium-based browsers. it is transparent. if you have an application like PowerPoint, or something, you can place the gif there to properly check its transparency. (doesn't work for webp though, needs to be opened in browser)

Comment: Chrome (and all major browsers) have supported GIF transparency for at least 15 years, and the GIF embedded in the question displays with a properly transparent background for me.... On a different note, I tried testing your code. The GIF-saving works fine, as you say, but trying to save the WebP throws `OSError: Background color is not an RGBA tuple clamped to (0-255): 0`, rather than saving any kind of file. Did neither of you two get this exception when testing this code? If not, that's perplexingly inconsistent, even for PIL's immature WebP support.

Comment: @CrazyChucky i didn't get any error. i am using latest version of python 3.10 with latest version of PIL

Comment: @IshanJ. Does [this](https://groups.google.com/a/webmproject.org/g/webp-discuss/c/VcfpaZ0fJeM) help?

Comment: Can you check if the transparency feature in webp is enabled? [See here](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/features.html#PIL.features.check_feature)

Comment: @MatrixProgrammer that is webp to gif, i want the reverse

Comment: @ShadowMitia yes it is enabled

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed it - there was literally 1 character wrong with your code!

Inside of gen_frame, it was `im = im.convert('RGB').convert('P', palette=Image.ADAPTIVE, colors=255)` and it should be `im = im.convert('RGBA').convert('P', palette=Image.ADAPTIVE, colors=255)`. As per one of my favorite YouTubers, "The truth hurts.". (Ben Finegold).

Correct:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageSequence


def gen_frame(im: Image) -> Image:
    alpha = im.getchannel('A')
    # Convert the image into P mode but only use 255 colors in the palette out of 256
    # -------------------------------------------
    # THE im.convert('RGB') WAS CHANGED TO "RGBA"
    # -------------------------------------------
    im = im.convert('RGBA').convert('P', palette=Image.ADAPTIVE, colors=255)
    # Set all pixel values below 128 to 255 , and the rest to 0
    mask = Image.eval(alpha, lambda a: 255 if a <= 128 else 0)
    # Paste the color of index 255 and use alpha as a mask
    im.paste(255, mask)
    # The transparency index is 255
    im.info['transparency'] = 255
    return im


im = Image.open("input_gif.gif")

im_list = []

for frame in ImageSequence.Iterator(im):
    # perform some functions on the image frames

    frame = frame.convert('RGBA').resize((512, 512), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    frame = gen_frame(frame)

    im_list.append(frame)

img = im_list[0]
imgs = im_list[1:]

img.save("output_gif.gif", save_all=True, append_images=imgs, duration=50, loop=0, optimize=False, disposal=2)
# works correctly, as intended

img.save("output_webp.webp", save_all=True, append_images=imgs, duration=50, loop=0, optimize=False, disposal=2, lossless=True)
# Transparency loss in the webp format
```

https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html#gif

From the docs:

> GIF
>
> Pillow reads GIF87a and GIF89a versions of the GIF file format. The library writes run-length encoded files in GIF87a by default, unless GIF89a features are used or GIF89a is already in use.
>
> GIF files are initially read as grayscale (L) or palette mode (P) images, but **seeking to later frames in an image will change the mode to either RGB or RGBA, depending on whether the first frame had transparency**.

So in essence, when you went to generate a frame for the image, you were not adding the alpha channel to it, despite setting the transparency in the info properties, and when you went to save it, it was lost.

As per the docs:

> transparency
>
> Transparency color index. This key is omitted if the image is not transparent.